# In The Pandorica Opens painting showing the explosion of the TARDIS, is it one TARDIS or two that explode?

Tags: doctor-who

The Pandorica Opens painting is strange. People see different things when they look at it.

[image: The exploding TARDIS painting from The Pandorica Opens]

Has the TARDIS broken into parts? Are we seeing two TARDISes? Or, are we looking at different moments of the TARDIS as the explosion is occurring?
The answer to this question obviously has major implications for the Dr. Who story.

Any reasonable answer will sensibly account of what we see in the painting. Alternatively, you may conclude that insufficient evidence exists to give a sensible account of what we see.

Comment: Pretty sure it's just one TARDIS but it's screwing up time, therefore the multiples and fractures.

Comment: @MeatTrademark - This appears to be a view of the sides and front being blown off.

Answer (score 7):

It’s one TARDIS. The painting doesn’t show multiple TARDISes, it shows multiple *bits* of the TARDIS — because multiple bits is what you get when you blow something up.

I would like to know *why* the TARDIS blew up though. We still don’t have an answer to that.

Comment: Thank you for posting the picture and taking your time to answer the question, now viewers of the page can see how strange The Pandorica Opens is.

Comment: Now we know why, as it was explained in *The Time of the Doctor*.

Comment: @Keavon: indeed we do! Well, kind of. “The Silence did it.” Okay. How?!?!?

Answer (score 5):

Most important thing to keep in mind; This is a van Gogh. A reference to their previous encounter with the painter.

Note that van Gogh was an impressionist painter, which means that it was more important for him what he *felt* than what he physically *saw*. Note further that there are three distinct pieces that resemble a TARDIS, not just two (note the left part with the instructions!).

This added together means that the theory of *two* TARDISes is out the window. The painting alludes to the notion that the entire universe (both in the meaning of "Doctor-Who-Universe" as literal universe) is falling apart with the Doctor sacrificing himself. **So, since it's an impressionist painting, it doesn't make sense to ask if it represents one, two or three actual TARDISes. It's not supposed to be literal evidence of an event, it's supposed to convey how an event was perceived.**

Answer (score -1):

I think there may be two TARDISes in the image. The visual evidence from the painting in inconclusive but inconclusiveness does not support a case for either one or two TARDISes.

There were some strange occurrences in The Pandorica Opens episode that may speak to the presence of another TARDIS. What seized control of the TARDIS away from River Song and directed it to Amy Pond's home? And what caused the loss of control of the TARDIS just before it was blown up? Influence on the control functions of one TARDIS by another is well established in the Dr. Who tradition so the presence of another TARDIS could explain this. In fact a TARDIS can also be used as a weapon to destroy another TARDIS (e.g. in a time ram) and it is one of the few effective tools that can be used to achieve that result.

Further evidence for the presence of a second TARDIS can be found at the end of the Cold Blood episode where the Doctor compares the piece of shrapnel he pulled from the other side of a crack in time with his TARDIS.

[image: The Doctor comparing the TARDIS fragment to the TARDIS itself]

The Doctor's shock in this scene is often thought to express his distress at seeing a piece of his TARDIS from the future, a future in which the TARDIS is destroyed. The scene can be viewed differently. The fragment of wreckage is different in several ways from the equivalent component on the Doctor's undamaged TARDIS. It is a different colour which may or may not be due to charring. Also, perhaps, there are several minor physical differences between the TARDIS component and the piece of wreckage. In particular, the sizing of the lettering on the piece of wreckage seems to be slightly but noticeably larger than the similar lettering on the TARDIS.

Taken together these points at least make it plausible that two TARDISes appear in the painting with one TARDIS either shadowing the Matt Smith/River Song TARDIS or being used as a weapon to destroy it.

Comment: “In particular, the sizing of the lettering on the piece of wreckage seems to be slightly but noticeably larger than the similar lettering on the TARDIS.” Really? Could you provide a screenshot in support of that? The Doctor does hold the fragment up against the actual TARDIS; it seemed to fit pretty well from what I remember, and there was no implication from the editing that suggested there was a difference.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite How many people on this site are justifying their answers in this fine grained way? You are skeptical fine, but if you doubt what I say check it for yourself in the Cold Blood episode. Also, its a guess and not too likely to be correct based on the Christmas special. You should decide whether you want to engage with people taking a different approach than yourself or be mildly ticked off by that difference.

Comment: I’m sorry if I sounded ticked off; I didn’t mean to. The purpose of Stack Exchange sites is to provide factual answers to questions (see e.g. http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/how-to-comment-on-answers-lacking-citations), rather than to provide a forum for discussion. (There is an attached chat site that you can access once you’ve got 20 rep points, where discussion is welcome.) I like your idea about two TARDISes, but without a bit more evidence from the show I don’t think it’s answer material. Sorry for seeming unfriendly though. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Remember I didn't think we get much past plausibilities with the known facts in this case. I checked the scene in Cold Blood again and the wreckage does not appear to be translucent as it should be if it were to be identical to Matt Smith's TARDIS. Is this due to charring or a scene continuity or prop problem? I don't know but it is a piece of information that supports my conjecture (irrespective of whether the conjecture is right or wrong). Until a story is wholly settled facts sit in close company with conjectures and imagined facts melt away just as easily as any invalid conjecture.

Comment: when you say “translucent”, what do you mean? As I understand it, “translucent” means “semi-transparent”, which the TARDIS isn’t (except when it’s materialising/dematerialising). I’ve added the best screenshot I can get of comparing the fragment to the TARDIS, and I reckon the colour difference looks like charring.

Comment: Thanks for posting the screenshot. I use "translucent" in the normal sense of the word as passing light while not being transparent. Maybe I should have said either translucent or luminescent. Matt Smith's TARDIS police telephone sign lights up at night (passing light or producing it) unlike all the other TARDISes of the earlier Doctors. In the scene you draw the screenshot from we see the piece of wreckage from many angles. So does it appear to have the qualities we would normally associate with translucent or luminescent materials? Not to me. That is a judgement call, others are possible.

Comment: No, it’s not a judgment call. It’s translucent if light partially passes through it. It doesn’t, so it’s not translucent.

Comment: To be identical to the same piece on Smith's TARDIS the wreckage would have to be translucent (or luminescent) because on Smith's TARDIS it lights up in low light, passing or emitting light. So when you say the piece of wreckage doesn't pass light that is evidence favourable to the two TARDIS account. Favourable not confirming because there is a judgement call that must also allow the differences are not due to charring, a continuity problem in the scene or the strange operation of the chameleon circuit. A similar judgement call can be made that would discount the differences for such reasons.

Comment: oh, I’m sorry, I see what you mean now. When you said the police telephone sign lights up at night, I thought you meant the “Police Box” wording at the top. I hadn’t noticed that the information sign lights up in the dark too (screenshots: [at night](http://cdn.pauldwaite.me.uk/images/tardis-illuminated-sign-1.png), and [indoors in dim lighting](http://cdn.pauldwaite.me.uk/images/tardis-illuminated-sign-2.png); and [discussion](http://tardisbuilders.com/index.php?topic=1596.0)). To me the illumination looks like a glow-in-the-dark effect, not translucency. But I do see what you mean.